# UIDynamics with Core Animation

Tags: uikit-dynamics

I have used `UIDynamics` before, but I never used it along with the methods provided by the Core Animation framework.

I basically would like to achieve something very simple:

I would like my UI Object to travel along a path and have another UI Object attached to it.

I create the `attachment behavior` like so:

```
attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:view2 attachedToItem:view1];
```

So, as `view1` being animated, `view2` will follow.

All this is working if I trigger it using a `UIPushBehavior`.

> My question is, is it possible to mix `UIDynamics` using:
>
> `CABasicAnimation`, `CAKeyFrameAnimation` and `[UIView ....]` animation block?

I tried to animate `view1` using an animation block.

***Result:*** while `view1` is being animated, `view2` is not being attached.

If I set off the above using a push behavior, it animates and `view2` is attached to `view1` without problem.

Again, is it possible applying `UIDynamics` behaviors to UI Objects while using `CABasicAnimation`, `CAKeyFrameAnimation` and `[UIView ....]` animation block for animation?

***Addendum:***

---

Thought I would add the animation block I use (didn't add it because I thought it was too juvenile and simple to mention), but for completeness' sake:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^
{
    view1.center = (CGPoint){320.0, 480.0};
}];
```

For `alloc` and `init`'ing `UIDynamics` properties it is done in `viewDidLoad`:

```
animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:view2 attachedToItem:view1];
[animator addBehavior:attachment];
```